# PHP How the forum thread url parameters work?

Tags: php, multithreading, url

Usually we passing url parameters by GET method,

- i.e.: example.com/product.php?**id=1234**

but most of the forum thread urls are without the ? symbol (like below), how they determine which are the parameters to be processed?

http:// community.abcforum.com/thread-**123456**.html

Comment: You can look for clean URLs and rewriting. Appropriate tags are [tag:.htaccess] and [tag:mod-rewrite]

Comment: Thank for your help. I just found the answer [Passing parameters in the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389245/passing-parameters-in-the-url-not-with-php-get?rq=1)