# Passing Parameters in PHP

Tags: php, parameters

I know how to process parameters using the GET URL method in PHP like this: example.com/?item=23413

However I'm curious on how a site like Producteev.com achieved a different structure parameter. Producteev is also built in PHP framework, it is a task management site and when you open a task a similar url is what you will get:
producteev.com/workspace/t/5263c59f7301964e000004 (something like a page)
and not something like:
producteev.com/workspace/?t=5263c59f7301964e000004

Stackoverflow's framework is ASP.NET, right? I would like also to know if this is a natural way of passing url parameters or query in ASP.NET: 
stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-do

Comment: **A:** [`mod_rewrite()`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: ah like this one? [mod rewrite and query strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604378/mod-rewrite-and-query-strings)

Comment: Yes, and there are many other examples that you will find by Googling "mod_rewrite tutorial"