# PHP - url path as parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters

I'm using PHP for creating websites. 
To change the content of the page, there is script which includes different files based on a URL parameter, eg. `http://example.com/index.php?page=news`. 
This loads some news page. When I want to load an exact article, I add another parameter like this:  `http://example.com/index.php?page=news&id=18964`,
but it does not look nice.
I want to have my URLs look like they are on this website: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`,
or in my case:  `http://example.com/news/18964`.

I would look on google, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: You need to apply mod rewriting rules to a .htaccess file, google that and you are sure to find many tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod rewrite and query strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604378/mod-rewrite-and-query-strings)

Comment: @DanielM duplicate is possible, I had no idea how to name this problem thus check for similar threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a full guide to mod_rewrite here that looks pretty good. You have to scroll down a bit to get to url as parameters.

https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

If you don't want to mess too much with mod_rewrite and already have everything directed through a single public index.php (which is a good idea anyway). Then you can do something a little more dirty like this.

```
/**
 * Get the given variable from $_REQUEST or from the url
 * @param string $variableName
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed|null
 */
function getParam($variableName, $default = null) {

    // Was the variable actually part of the request
    if(array_key_exists($variableName, $_REQUEST))
        return $_REQUEST[$variableName];

    // Was the variable part of the url
    $urlParts = explode('/', preg_replace('/\?.+/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $position = array_search($variableName, $urlParts);
    if($position !== false && array_key_exists($position+1, $urlParts))
        return $urlParts[$position+1];

    return $default;
}
```

Note that this checks for any _GET, _POST or _HEADER parameter with the same name first. Then it checks each part of the url for a given key, and returns the following part. So you can do something like:

```
// On http://example.com/news/18964
getParam('news');
// returns 18964
```